# Good Wishing for someone's success

Tags: grammar, usage

Here are some sentences:

Can I use 'May' for wishing someone? For example:

> May you get success in your goal.

OR,

Is it compulsory to use the word 'wish' for wishing someone ? For example:

> I wish you get success in your goal.
>
> I wish you succeed in your goal.
>
> I would rather you got success in your goal.

Comment: @P.E Dent why I'm getting close votes ?

Comment: Because there are hundreds of answers to the question _"What is the best way of wishing someone to get success in his goal?"_ Everyone has an opinion about "the best way".

Comment: Umm . . .what would you suggest me to improve this question?

Comment: I've edited my question,

Comment: Thanks for the edit! :-)  I've reopened this post, as the "primarily opinion-based" close reason no longer applies.

Answer (score -4):

I wish you success with your goal. Not in the goal. The word "get" needs to be dropped. It's a lazy word meaning it's frequently used instead of being more direct. Like saying, " Do you get my meaning" instead of "Do you understand my meaning". The word "in" implies being contained within. "In your goal" would be better used to talk about a step in completing your goal. "May you have success with your goal" would work also. Try using get less and only when you are physically reaching for something.

Comment: What about my first sentence with 'May' ? Can't I use 'May you get success with your goal ? Why can't I use 'In' ?

Comment: You don't say "May you get". "May you have" is more correct.

Comment: This answer has many downvote so I don't know how to believe this answer. I'm puzzled

Comment: There are many ways to say what you want to say as @P.E. Dent said. I attributed the down votes to those people who had a difference of opinion. It was also before I put my complete answer together as an edit. There haven't been any further down votes since I put up my complete answer. Also, no one has given another answer. I am an English Teacher so this is exactly what I would have taught my students when I was teaching. I have no reason to steer you wrong.

Comment: I would have down voted my first attempt to help. It gave no reason or explanation. And 3 down votes isn't that many. It was my first attempt to help someone and I apologize for being so brief at first. But thank you for giving me my first experience at helping someone. I have given you all the information I can to try to help. It's up to you to use it as you wish. May you have success with your goal.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thank you for answering me. But I think,who down voted your answer, should have put their comments below your answer explaining what should be improved and what parts should be removed according to them. Down votes without any reason is worthless.